# Actions from Kony Visualizer are not imported to Kony Studio

Tags: temenos-quantum

I have an action in Visualizer under Form > Action > preShow which invokes a function. If I export it and import it in Kony Studio the action is not carried over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled on the option to use the Visualizer actions in Kony Studio by right-clicking on the project -> Properties -> Build -> Use Visualizer Actions.

Answer (score 3):

If you flip on "Use Visualizer Actions" you will be able to use the actions defined in Visualizer, yes, but be advised that from then on, **any actions you define in Studio will not work**.

Visualizer and Studio actions are mutually exclusive. And for good reason. Your designer may have hardwired a lot of actions to make the prototype actionable, but those actions must be replaced with real logic on the actual application.

If you're both the designer and developer or for some other reason do want to leverage your Visualizer actions and continue to enhance them, then the best practice is to place your Visualizer actions in modules, rather than the "point and click" way. Modules defined in Visualizer can be imported into Studio and will work without flipping anything or excluding anything else.

I hope this helps.